# Don't count on seeing me anywhere

Tags: grammar, sentence

Are there any mistakes in these sentences?

> Don't count on **me being** anywhere.
>   Don't count on **seeing me** anywhere.

I think the last sentence should be : **Don't count on me seeing anywhere**. What's your opinion about this?

[image]

Comment: Your version doesn't make sense. The sentence in the image means 'Don't expect that you will see me anywhere.'

Comment: But the Longman dictionary suggested the structure like this : count on (somebody/something) doing something. Link : https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/count-on-upon

Comment: I can't understand what's the difference between these two sentence : 1. Don't count on me being anywhere. 2. Don't count on seeing me anywhere.

Comment: @Ador You've misunderstood both the dictionary and the words in the picture. **1** *So, don't count on me being anywhere* = Thus, you should not feel confident **that I** will be a particular place. ++ **2** *Don't count on seeing me anywhere* =  you should not feel confident **that you** might see me at any place.

Comment: I have transcribed the relevant information from the graphic into the question itself. As a note, don't rely only on pictures, as some people use screen readers that can't read images.

Comment: @Ador Also, you are conflating two different things. You can't change the verb *and* the construction and then ask what the difference is. Pick either the verb *or* the construction. Or ask about both. For example, you have excluded two other possibilities. (3) *Don't count on **being me** anywhere.* (4) *Don't count on **me seeing** anywhere.* All ***four*** sentences mean something different. But you're not focusing on a single difference.

Comment: Actually the problem is, I can't differentiate between  these two sentences:  (1) Don't count on me being anywhere. (2) Don't count on seeing me anywhere because the Longman dictionary suggested a structure like this: count on (somebody/someone) doing something. And I wanted to know the reason why those sentences were used differently.

Comment: The 'somebody' doing the seeing (or not) is **you** (the reader). You will not be seeing 'me' (the person posting the message).

Comment: Please fix your title.